# Azure multiple web sites with one role but some don't get rebuilt when I publish

Tags: azure

I have six web sites and one web role. Now I notice that when I publish the web sites all except for the one that's part of the role are not rebuilt. Is there any way I can run a MSBUILD command to build a web site after the main web site for the role has been built?

Answer (score 5):

I just found my answer :-)

This is because, by default, the Windows Azure project has no dependency on secondary web sites so the build process can choose to compile these projects after the packaging is complete. You can change this by right-clicking the Windows Azure project node in Visual Studio’s Solution Explorer, choose Project Dependencies, and tell it to depend on all projects that need to be included in the deployment package: