# Windows Azure with Multiple Sites in One Role not transforming 2nd web.debug.config to web.config

Tags: web-config, azure, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Web.Config transformations to deploy my application to Azure.  I also have 2 sites in my service, a public website, and private WCF site endpoint.  I am deploying [multiple sites to a single role](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/).

When I deploy, the website project (for which the Azure Deploy project is set) transforms the web.config correctly.  However, the WCF project (which is only addressed as a "site" in the .csdef file) does not transform the web.debug.config file to web.config.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134875/azure-multiple-web-sites-with-one-role-but-some-dont-get-rebuilt-when-i-publish) is similar, but only addresses the projects building.  I have set the dependencies in my project.

[This workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181917/azure-multiple-sites-on-1-role-physical-directory-post-build-event) forces the transform of the web.config file, but it still does not appear in my deployment on Azure.

I suspect that [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641913/visual-studio-azure-tools-sdk-1-3-not-packaging-multiple-sites-correctly) still exists, and I have also upgraded to the [Azure 1.5 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh403991.aspx) in hopes that it will fix it.

I would like to try putting my [configuration data in cscfg files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734776/azure-web-config-per-environment) but I am using Entity Framework Code First, and I do not know how to get my connection string to work with this format.  EFCF seems to rely on web.config explicitly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's how you [set connection strings in Entity Framework Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=VS.103).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you add another web role, you provide a physicalPath to point to what you want deployed, and all the SDK does is copy the files it finds at that path into your package. It doesn't do a build.

You should probably be doing a build and a publish of the web app you want to deploy, and then point the physicalDirectory at the *output* of that publish step. (Make sure the directory you're setting in physicalDirectory contains exactly what you want to have deployed to the cloud.)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for your help.
[This workaround](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641913/visual-studio-azure-tools-sdk-1-3-not-packaging-multiple-sites-correctly) published to ..\MyApp.Services\sites\MyApp.Services while I had PhysicalLocation pointed to ..\MyApp.Services.   

Changing that used the correct web transform.

Comment: If you wanted a more complete walkthrough of this, please see 
http://kellyhpdx.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/deploying-multiple-web-applications-to-a-single-azure-instance-and-applying-web-config-transforms-correctly/

Comment: I was able to get the workaround in Rob Potter's link to work.