# Build transformations when publishing multiple-websites WebRole

Tags: asp.net, azure, publish, web.config-transform, webrole

I have added multiple sites inside a azure web role, like below:

```
 <WebRole name="site1" vmsize="Small">
  <Sites>
    <Site name="site1" physicalDirectory="..\site1">
      <Bindings>
        <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="www.site1.nl" />
      </Bindings>
    </Site>
    <Site name="site2" physicalDirectory="..\site2">
      <Bindings>
        <Binding name="ndpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="www.site2.nl" />
      </Bindings>
    </Site>
  </Sites>
  ......
```

I have added two configurations for each web application to make database connection string different -> Web.Dev.Config and Web.Staging.Config.

When i right click the Cloud Service projcet -> 'Publish', and choose the 'Build configuration' to 'Dev', these two web site were be published successful.

But in the site2, the connection string inside Web.config seems incorrect , the folder of site2 contains all configurations of web.config files like Web.Dev.config and Web.Staging.config, and all cs files still exists, it seems the site2 was not build correctly.

Is there anybody has experience about this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I've found a few other articles that explain how to resolve this.

https://kellyhpdx.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/deploying-multiple-web-applications-to-a-single-azure-instance-and-applying-web-config-transforms-correctly/

[Windows Azure with Multiple Sites in One Role not transforming 2nd web.debug.config to web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487285/windows-azure-with-multiple-sites-in-one-role-not-transforming-2nd-web-debug-con)